# Decreasing the time to load from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android, optimization, memory

I want to optimize my code to reduce the run time of my application. Currently it takes 18secs to load and show the welcome screen.

I am using AsyncTask to put all of my operation(JSON parsing, Database operations). Is there any else method that I can use to shave off at least 4secs from my application.

I can show the code if you want. Please let me know.

Thanking you

I've shared the code here please go through it.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
/** THE FOLLOWING STRINGS WILL BE DISPLAYED IN LOGCAT */

final String TAG = "##--MAIN ACTIVITY--##";

UserHelper userAdapter;

Context context;
String regName="";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
String regNameSplit[];
JSONObject second_jsonObj = null; 
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
JSONObject jsonobj = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    userAdapter = new UserHelper(this);
    context = getApplicationContext();


    final EditText edit_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    final EditText edit_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    final EditText edit_company = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.company_string);

    final Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            /*THE IF STATEMENT CHECKS IF THE FIELDS ARE EMPTY OR NOT*/
             if (edit_username.getText().toString().equals("") || edit_username.getText().toString() == null ||
                        edit_password.getText().toString().equals("") || edit_password.getText().toString() == null||
                        edit_company.getText().toString().equals("") ||edit_company.getText().toString() == null ){
                 Log.i(TAG,"User has left some fields empty");  
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter all details", duration).show();
                } else{ 
                    jsonobj = new JSONObject();
            try{

                //THE TRY STATEMENT CREATES A NEW JSON OBJECT TO BE PARSED IN HANDLEJSON METHOD//
                JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();
                subJson.put("username", edit_username.getText().toString()/*"da"*/);
                subJson.put("password", edit_password.getText().toString()/*"exicom"*/);
                subJson.put("company", edit_company.getText().toString()/*"utb17"*/);
                jsonobj.put("user", subJson);
                Log.i(TAG,""+jsonobj);
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                Log.i("","#####-----error at catch jsonexception-----#####");

            }

            //JSON OBJECT IS PARSED OVER HERE //
            new synchronizeData(URL, jsonobj).execute(); 
                }
        }
    });
}

class synchronizeData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{

    private String name1;
    private String company1;
    private String password1;
    private String regnaMe1;
    private String reg1name1;
    ProgressDialog PD ;

    public synchronizeData(String name, String password, String company,
            String regnaMe, String reg1name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name1 = name;
        this.company1 = company;
        this.password1 = password;
        this.regnaMe1 = regnaMe;
        this.reg1name1 = reg1name ;

    }

    public synchronizeData(String uRL, JSONObject jsonobj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v(TAG,"Start of doInBackground");
        try{    
            //Log.v(TAG,"The url is ********* "+URL);
            //Log.v(TAG, "Json object request is "+jsonobj.toString());
            DefaultHttpClient httpClientInstance = GetHttpClient.getHttpClientInstance();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
            Log.v(TAG,"The url is ********* "+URL);

            StringEntity se;
            se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClientInstance.execute(httpPostRequest);
            //Log.i(TAG, "HTTPRESPONSE RECIEVED in " +(System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms");

                String resultString = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                //Log.v(TAG ,/* "The response is "resultString);
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(resultString);
                JSONObject sessionJson = jsonObj.getJSONObject("session");
                String sessionId = sessionJson.getString("sessionid");
                String name = sessionJson.getString("name");
                //Log.v(TAG,"The session ID is "+sessionId);
                //Log.v(TAG,"The name is "+name);
                regName = name+"-"+sessionId+"-"+URL;

    } catch (JSONException e){
        try{
            Log.i(TAG,"JSON EXCEPTION FIRST");
            JSONObject messageJson = jsonObj.getJSONObject("message");
            String typeJson = messageJson.getString("type");
            String contentJson = messageJson.getString("content");

            regName = contentJson;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(JSONException jse){
            jse.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch(Exception ee){
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v(TAG,"before the return statement "+regName.toString());
    //return regName;


        try{
             String regNameSplit[] = regName.split("-");
            if(regNameSplit[0].equals("Invalid username or password")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+regNameSplit[0], duration).show();
            }
                else{

                String regnaMe = regNameSplit[0].toString();
                String reg1name = regNameSplit[1].toString();
                Log.v(regnaMe,reg1name);





            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("regName", regNameSplit[0]);
            intent.putExtra("regName_sessionID", regNameSplit[1]);
            intent.putExtra("regName_URL", regNameSplit[2]);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            userAdapter.openDatabase();
//-------------THE DATABASE CHECKS IF THE VALUE IS PRESENT OR NOT IF TRUE DOESN'T INSERT-----------//
            if(db.Exists(name1) == true){

            } else {

                long id = db.insertIntoDatabase(name1,company1,password1,regnaMe1,reg1name1);
                Log.i(TAG, "Printing value of id which will be inserted only to remove warnings "+id);
                    }           
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private java.lang.String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try{
            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null ){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        PD.setMessage("Please wait....");
        PD.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        PD.dismiss();
        userAdapter.closeDatabase();
    }

}
```

}

This is the code for the second activity:

String ht = "";
    public final String TAG = "###---Secondactivity---###";
    public String reg_name = "";
    public String resultString = "";

```
// AccessTimeReportTableHelper dB;
JSONObject jsonobj = null;
Vector objVector = new Vector();
String bufferedValue = "";
String newdeletedtrsArray = "";
String newschemaArray = "";
String newtrsArray = "";
String URL_ = "";
AccessTimeReportTableHelper useradapter_TimeReportTable;
AccessMessageTable useradapterMessageTable;
AccessMessageTypeTable useradapterMessageTypeTable;
UserHelper userHelper;
AccessTimeReportMessage useradapterTimeReportMessage;

String[] split_newdeletedtrsArray;
String[] split_newschemaArray;
String[] split_newtrsArray;
String[] splitno1_split_newtrsArray;
ArrayList<GetSetMethod> bulk = new ArrayList<GetSetMethod>();
ProgressDialog PD;
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unused" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
    Log.v(TAG, "Start of second activity");
    userHelper = new UserHelper(this);
    useradapterMessageTable = new AccessMessageTable(this);
    useradapter_TimeReportTable = new AccessTimeReportTableHelper(this);
    useradapterMessageTypeTable = new AccessMessageTypeTable(this);
    useradapterTimeReportMessage = new AccessTimeReportMessage(this);

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("regName") != null) {
        try {
            String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("regName");
            String session_ID = getIntent().getStringExtra(
                    "regName_sessionID");
            URL_ = "URL inserted here";

            jsonobj = new JSONObject("custom JSON OBJECT HERE");

            String ht = URL_ + "&" + jsonobj;
            // Log.i("" + ht, "");

            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            String resultString = "";
            String deletedtrsArray = "";
            String newtrsArray = "";
            String newschemaArray = "";
            String bufferedValue = "";


            Log.v(TAG, "The url is " + URL_);
             Log.v(TAG, "Json object request is " + jsonobj.toString());
            new AsyncSecondActivity(jsonobj).execute();

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception en) {
            en.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.v(TAG, "Ending program execution here");

}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

class AsyncSecondActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    private String newcompanyid1;
    private String newdate1;
    private String newusername1;
    private String newClientId1;
    private String newprojectId1;
    private String newniV1;
    private String newniV2;
    private String newworktypeid1;
    private String newtimetypeid1;
    private String newhours1;
    private String newcomment1;
    private String newprivatecomment1;
    private String newopen1;
    private String newreportid1;

    String messageTypeId = "";
    String messageConcat = "";
    String concatCursorCompare = "";
    String newcompanyid;
    String date_id = "";
    String compareId = "";
    String newusername = "";
    String newdate = "";
    String newClientId = "";
    String newprojectId = "";
    String newniv1 = "";
    String newniv2 = "";
    String newworktypeid = "";
    String newtimetypeid = "";
    String newhours = "";
    String newcomment = "";
    String newprivatecomment = "";
    String newopen = "";
    String newreportid = "";
    String dateId = "";
    String messageType_System = "";
    String message_content = "";
    String userId_FirstActivity = "";
    String date = "";
    String report = "";
    // Cursor DECLARATION//
    Cursor c = null;
    Cursor cur = null;
    Cursor curMessageTable = null;
    Cursor curMessageName = null;
    Cursor curMainActivity = null;
    Cursor curTimeReportMessage = null;

    public AsyncSecondActivity(JSONObject jsonobj) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Value of BULK in AsyncSecondActivity (GETSET METHOD) "
                + jsonobj);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
        DefaultHttpClient httpClientInstance = GetHttpClient
                .getHttpClientInstance();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL_);
         Log.v(TAG, "The url is " + URL_);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClientInstance
                .execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG,
                "HTTPRESPONSE RECIEVED in "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + "ms");
        resultString = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                .getContent());

        // Log.v(TAG , "The response is " +resultString);

        jsonobj = new JSONObject(resultString);
        JSONObject sync_reponse = jsonobj.getJSONObject("syncresponse");
        String synckey_string = sync_reponse.getString("synckey");
        JSONArray createdtrs_array = sync_reponse
                .getJSONArray("createdtrs");

        JSONArray modtrs_array = sync_reponse.getJSONArray("modtrs");
        // -----HANDLING MODTRS-----//
        for (int n = 0; n < modtrs_array.length(); n++) {
            JSONObject object = modtrs_array.getJSONObject(n);
            String newcompanyID_mod = object.getString("companyid");
            String newusername_mod = object.getString("username");
            String newdate_mod = object.getString("date");
            String newclientid_mod = object.getString("clientid");
            String newprojectid_mod = object.getString("projectid");
            String newniv1_mod = object.getString("niv1");
            String newniv2_mod = object.getString("niv2");
            String newworktypeid_mod = object.getString("worktypeid");
            String newtimetypeid_mod = object.getString("timetypeid");
            String newhours_mod = object.getString("hours");
            String newcomment_mod = object.getString("comment");
            String newprivatecomment_mod = object
                    .getString("privatecomment");
            String newopen_mod = object.getString("open");

            if ((object.has("message"))) {
                JSONObject messaget = object.getJSONObject("message");
                String newtype = object.getJSONObject("message")
                        .getString("type");
                String newcontent = object.getJSONObject("message")
                        .getString("content");

                GetSetMethod objSample = new GetSetMethod();
                objSample.setnewclientid_mod(newclientid_mod);
                objSample.setnewusername_mod(newusername_mod);
                objSample.setnewdate_mod(newdate_mod);
                objSample.setnewprojectid_mod(newprojectid_mod);
                objSample.setNewniv1(newniv1_mod);
                objSample.setNewniv2(newniv2_mod);
                objSample.setNewworktypeid(newworktypeid_mod);
                objSample.setNewtimetypeid(newtimetypeid_mod);
                objSample.setNewhours(newhours_mod);
                objSample.setNewcomment(newcomment_mod);
                objSample.setNewopen(newopen_mod);
                objSample.setNewprivatecomment(newprivatecomment_mod);
            }
        }

        JSONArray deletedtrs_array = sync_reponse
                .getJSONArray("deletedtrs");

        // -----------------------HANDLING
        // DELETEDTRS------------------------//

        for (int n = 0; n < deletedtrs_array.length(); n++) {
            JSONObject object = deletedtrs_array.getJSONObject(n);
            String newUserName = object.getString("username");
            String newCompanyId = object.getString("companyid");
            String newDate = object.getString("date");
            String newReportId = object.getString("reportid");
        }

        JSONArray newtrs_array = sync_reponse.getJSONArray("newtrs");

        // -----------------------HANDLING
        // NEWTRS----------------------------//

        GetSetMethod objSample = null;

        for (int n = 0; n < newtrs_array.length(); n++) {
            JSONObject object = newtrs_array.getJSONObject(n);
            String newcompanyid = object.getString("companyid");
            String newusername = object.getString("username");
            String newdate = object.getString("date");
            String newClientId = object.getString("clientid");
            String newprojectId = object.getString("projectid");
            String newniv1 = object.getString("niv1");
            String newniv2 = object.getString("niv2");
            String newworktypeid = object.getString("worktypeid");
            String newtimetypeid = object.getString("timetypeid");
            String newhours = object.getString("hours");
            String newcomment = object.getString("comment");
            String newprivatecomment = object
                    .getString("privatecomment");
            String newopen = object.getString("open");
            String newreportid = object.getString("reportid");

            String newcontent_mod = "";
            String newtype_mod = "";
            if ((object.has("message"))) {

                JSONObject message = object.getJSONObject("message");
                newtype_mod = object.getJSONObject("message")
                        .getString("type");
                newcontent_mod = object.getJSONObject("message")
                        .getString("content");
                // objSample = new GetSetMethod();
                // objSample.setnewcontent_mod(newcontent_mod);
                // objSample.setnewtype_mod(newtype_mod);

            }

            objSample = new GetSetMethod();
            objSample.setNewcompanyid(newcompanyid);
            objSample.setNewusername(newusername);
            objSample.setNewdate(newdate);
            objSample.setNewClientId(newClientId);
            objSample.setNewprojectId(newprojectId);
            objSample.setNewniv1(newniv1);
            objSample.setNewniv2(newniv2);
            objSample.setNewworktypeid(newworktypeid);
            objSample.setNewtimetypeid(newtimetypeid);
            objSample.setNewhours(newhours);
            objSample.setNewcomment(newcomment);
            objSample.setNewprivatecomment(newprivatecomment);
            objSample.setNewopen(newopen);
            objSample.setNewreportid(newreportid);
            if ((newcontent_mod) != null || (newtype_mod) != null) {
                objSample.setnewcontent_mod(newcontent_mod);
                objSample.setnewtype_mod(newtype_mod);
            }

            bulk.add(objSample);

            objSample.getNewClientId();

            for (int i = 0; i < objVector.size(); i++) {
                GetSetMethod objtest = new GetSetMethod();
                objtest = (GetSetMethod) objVector.get(i);
                objtest.getNewClientId();
                objtest.getNewcompanyid();
            }

        }
        //new AsyncSecondActivity(bulk).execute();

        // -----------------------HANDLING
        // SCHEMA-------------------------//
        JSONArray schema_array = sync_reponse.getJSONArray("schema");
        for (int n = 0; n < schema_array.length(); n++) {
            JSONObject object = schema_array.getJSONObject(n);
            String new_yearmonth = object.getString("yearmonth");
            String new_hoursperday = object.getString("hoursperday");
        }
        } catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HashMap<String, String> recordExist = new HashMap<String, String>();
        userHelper.openDatabase();
        useradapter_TimeReportTable.openDatabase();
        useradapterMessageTable.openDatabase();
        useradapterMessageTypeTable.openDatabase();
        useradapterTimeReportMessage.openDatabase();

        curMainActivity = userHelper.retrieveUserId();
        cur = useradapter_TimeReportTable.getUniqueRecordsId();
        curMessageTable = useradapterMessageTable.getMessageTable();
        curMessageName = useradapterMessageTypeTable.getMessageTypeId();

        for (int i = 0; i < bulk.size(); i++) {
            GetSetMethod objtest = bulk.get(i);
            this.newcompanyid1 = objtest.getNewcompanyid();
            this.newusername1 = objtest.getNewusername();
            this.newworktypeid1 = objtest.getNewworktypeid();
            this.newniV2 = objtest.getNewniv2();
            this.newniV1 = objtest.getNewniv1();
            this.newdate1 = objtest.getNewdate();
            this.newClientId1 = objtest.getNewClientId();
            this.newprojectId1 = objtest.getNewprojectId();
            this.newtimetypeid1 = objtest.getNewtimetypeid();
            this.newhours1 = objtest.getNewhours();
            this.newcomment1 = objtest.getNewcomment();
            this.newprivatecomment1 = objtest.getNewprivatecomment();
            this.newopen1 = objtest.getNewopen();
            this.newreportid1 = objtest.getNewreportid();
            this.message_content = objtest.getnewcontent_mod();
            this.messageType_System = objtest.getnewtype_mod();

            concatCursorCompare = date + "-" + report;
            //Log.v("Line number 408: SecondActivity", "Value: " + date);
            //Log.v("Line number 409: SecondActivity", "Value: " + report);
            recordExist.put(concatCursorCompare, concatCursorCompare);
            compareId = objtest.getNewdate() + "-"
                    + objtest.getNewreportid();
            if (!recordExist.containsValue(compareId)) {
                long id = useradapter_TimeReportTable
                        .insertIntoDatabase(newcompanyid1,
                                newusername1, newdate1, newClientId1,
                                newprojectId1, newniV1, newniV2,
                                newworktypeid1, newtimetypeid1,
                                newhours1, newcomment1,
                                newprivatecomment1, newopen1,
                                newreportid1, userId_FirstActivity);

            }
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                date = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("dateId"));
                report = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("reportId"));
            } 
            while(cur.moveToNext());
        }


            if (curMessageName.moveToFirst()) {
                messageTypeId = curMessageName.getString(curMessageName
                        .getColumnIndex("messageTypeId"));

            }
            else {

                    if (messageType_System != null && messageType_System != "") {
                        long ins_msg_typ_tbl = useradapterMessageTypeTable
                                .insertintoMessageTypeName(messageType_System);

                        curMessageName = useradapterMessageTypeTable.recordExistsmessageTypeTable(messageType_System);
                        if (curMessageName.moveToFirst()) {
                            messageTypeId = curMessageName.getString(curMessageName
                                    .getColumnIndex("messageTypeId"));

                        }
                    }
                }




            if (curMainActivity.moveToFirst()) {
                userId_FirstActivity = curMainActivity
                        .getString(curMainActivity
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("userId"));

            } 


            concatCursorCompare = date + "-" + report;
            Log.v("Line number 408: SecondActivity", "Value: " + date);
            Log.v("Line number 409: SecondActivity", "Value: " + report);
            recordExist.put(concatCursorCompare, concatCursorCompare);
            compareId = objtest.getNewdate() + "-"
                    + objtest.getNewreportid();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bulk.size(); i++) {
            GetSetMethod objtest = bulk.get(i);
            this.newcompanyid1 = objtest.getNewcompanyid();
            this.newusername1 = objtest.getNewusername();
            this.newworktypeid1 = objtest.getNewworktypeid();
            this.newniV2 = objtest.getNewniv2();
            this.newniV1 = objtest.getNewniv1();
            this.newdate1 = objtest.getNewdate();
            this.newClientId1 = objtest.getNewClientId();
            this.newprojectId1 = objtest.getNewprojectId();
            this.newtimetypeid1 = objtest.getNewtimetypeid();
            this.newhours1 = objtest.getNewhours();
            this.newcomment1 = objtest.getNewcomment();
            this.newprivatecomment1 = objtest.getNewprivatecomment();
            this.newopen1 = objtest.getNewopen();
            this.newreportid1 = objtest.getNewreportid();
            this.message_content = objtest.getnewcontent_mod();
            this.messageType_System = objtest.getnewtype_mod();

            try {
                compareId = objtest.getNewdate() + "-"
                        + objtest.getNewreportid();
                if(message_content != null && message_content !=""){
                long insertMessageTable = useradapterMessageTable.insertintoMessageTable(messageTypeId,message_content);

                }
                if(message_content != null && message_content !="" && report!=null && report != ""){
                    long  insertTimeReportMessage = useradapterTimeReportMessage.insertintoTimeReportMessgeTable(report, messageTypeId, date);
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (curMainActivity != null) {
                    curMainActivity.close();
                    curMainActivity = null;
                }
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                    c = null;
                }
                if (cur != null) {
                    cur.close();
                    cur = null;
                }
                if (curMessageTable != null) {
                    curMessageTable.close();
                    curMessageTable = null;
                }
                if (curMessageName != null) {
                    curMessageName.close();
                    curMessageName = null;
                }
                if(curTimeReportMessage != null){
                    curTimeReportMessage.close();
                    curTimeReportMessage = null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) throws SQLiteException {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        PD.dismiss();
        userHelper.closeDatabase();
        useradapter_TimeReportTable.closeDatabase();
        useradapterMessageTable.closeDatabase();
        useradapterMessageTypeTable.closeDatabase();
        useradapterTimeReportMessage.closeDatabase();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Welcome " + getIntent().getStringExtra("regName"),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            PD = new ProgressDialog(Secondactivity.this);
            PD.setTitle("Please wait");
            PD.setMessage("Updating records");
            PD.show();
        } catch (Exception progressDialog) {
            progressDialog.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**To put in simple terms I will take a username password and insert it into the database. After I get a JSON response from webservice (got by sending the username and password) I parse the JSON object to a string and then insert it into the database.**

**In the second activity I obtain a JSON response that I parse and convert the input to a string. I then insert the JSON response into their respective databases.**

Comment: yes, If possible, Share code here.

Comment: 18 seconds... - On a real device or on the emulator?

Comment: Hint (OT): Instead of *edit_username.getText().toString().equals("")* you can use *edit_username.getText().length() == 0*.

Comment: Hanno Binder: 18 secs on the emulator

Comment: Additional idee:  instead of reading stream into string, which is suboptimal in terms of memory alloaction and time consumption you should stick with pull JSON parser ( like GSON ) and utilize databinding ( I released simple one: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator is slow - normal device could be much faaster.   One potential source for delay woud be UserHelper Object creation - you  provided no source code  for it.  You also omited code for onResume() methods of your activities.  Best way to find where performance has gone, would be to perform profiling run with ddms.